# CorePlot CPTPlotAreaFrame

Tags: core-plot

Trying to change the padding on the graph.plotAreaFrame during the life of the graph

```
func plotConfigurationViewControllerPadding(_ plotConfigurationViewController: PlotConfigurationViewController, userSelectedPaddingChanged changed: Bool, padding: CGFloat) {
       if changed {
            thisplot.padding = padding
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.paddingTop = thisplot.padding
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.paddingBottom = thisplot.padding
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.paddingLeft = thisplot.padding
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.paddingRight = thisplot.padding
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.plotArea?.updateAxisSetLayers(for: CPTGraphLayerType.majorGridLines)
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.plotArea?.updateAxisSetLayers(for: CPTGraphLayerType.minorGridLines)
            graph.plotAreaFrame?.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true

            saveToDatabase()
        }
    }
```

Code here repositions the plots, but doesn't shift axes, labels, gridlines etc
How to I make this work?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "shift" the axes, etc.? Can you provide a screenshot that illustrates the problem?

Comment: in this context shift means reposition the axes, labels, gridlines to accommodate the change in padding value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the padding on the `graph`. This will inset everything from the edges of the graph.

You don't normally need to call `updateAxisSetLayers()`. Core Plot calls it internally when required.

Comment: Nah, I had to redraw the whole graph from scratch